# Store values of SQL query in variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a SELECT SQL statement that returns a Latitude, Longitude and Distance as result (using the Haversine formula).  Now I need to store these values as variables within the PHP script as I need to do further processing on the results.  Can anyone tell me how I can do this?

Here is my SQL Statement

**UPDATED**

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT `Latitude`, `Longitude`, (6378160 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + sin( radians(:latitude) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `mytable` HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance;");
// Assign parameters
$query->bindParam(':latitude',$newLatitude);
$query->bindParam(':longitude',$newLongitude);
$query->bindParam(':radius',$radius);

//Execute query
$query->execute();
$q   = $db->query($query);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// fetch
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  $eLatitude = $r->Latitude;
  $eLongitude = $r>Longitude;
  $distance = $r->Distance;
}
```

I updated my php code above.  Is this code's syntax correct? Or the way I'm doing it is all wrong?

Comment: execute query and in while loop fetch results and assign them to variables, what's the problem

Comment: Also, there are much more efficient ways to do this if you search here for mysql geolocation.

Comment: @vodich I am new to PDO/PHP altogether so I am not pretty sure how this can be done

Comment: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Posibble-Fetch-Mode-P548.html

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php ?

Comment: @vodich  I have updated my code.  Is this how it is done or I am completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO::FETCH_ASSOC: returns an array indexed by column name [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  echo $r['Latitude']. "\n"; //Or do what ever instead of echo
  echo $r['Longitude']. "\n";
  echo $r['Distance']. "\n";
}

ie XML
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat",  $r['Latitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng",  $r['Longitude']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance",  $r['Distance']);
}

ie JSON
while($r = $q->fetch()){
  data[] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$queryresult = mysql_query("SELECT `Latitude`, `Longitude`, (6378160 * acos( cos( radians(:latitude) ) * cos( radians( Latitude ) ) * cos( radians( Longitude ) - radians(:longitude) ) + sin( radians(:latitude) ) * sin( radians( Latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM `mytable` HAVING distance < :radius ORDER BY distance;");
if (!$queryresult) {
    echo 'Error ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$resultrow = mysql_fetch_row($queryresult);

echo $resultrow[0];  // this will be latitude
echo $resultrow[1];  // this will be longitude
```

Comment: Since the original mysql functions have now been deprecated and will be removed in the future, please don't provide examples using the mysql functions, especially when the person asking the question is already using MySQLi.